# Load part of JSON with `json` and part with `pandas` in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file that contains "informational" fields, followed by a massive "data" array (also in JSON format). I'll analyze the data array as a Pandas DataFrame. I'm trying to make my script robust to possibly enormous JSON files.

So I'd like to avoid loading the massive data array into memory twice.  For example, the following code will create the `Data` array (which could eventually be huge) twice, - once with `json.load()`, and a second time with `pandas.DataFrame.from_records()`.

Example JSON file "*dummydata.json*" :

```
      {
      "ID":4,
      "DUT":"Resistor1",
      "Timestamp":"2022-09-23T16:56:29.653-05:00",
      "Voltage Units":"V",
      "Measurement Time Units":"hr",
      "Current Units":"A",
      "Data":{
              "Voltage":9.9984,
              "Measurement Time":[ 0.000085, 0.000363, 0.000641, ... ],
              "Current":[ 0.000000, 0.010600, 0.010500, ... ],
             }
      }
```

(You can see the `Data` dict at the end is the part that can become very large over time, as we record Current over a very long time.)

```
# Load the whole JSON file
import json
data = json.load(   open('dummydata.json', 'r')   )
    
# Create Pandas DataFrame from measurement data:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(   data['Data']   )
```

The above code has loaded the Data array into both a Dict `data` and a DataFrame `df`, which seems inefficient at best. Currently I'm only loading ~215k lines as we test the system, but I expect this to become up to 10 Million data lines in later renditions.

Is there a convenient way to grab only the "informational" fields from the JSON file (and avoid the "Data" dict),
then have Pandas load *only* the "Data" dict?
Or another way to sequentially load huge datafiles without overloading system memory (for things like plotting)?

By "convenient" I mean without me writing code to parse the file line by line myself, which I can certainly do, but hopefully this is a problem already solved by some brilliant module out there.  Maybe indexing into the data file by line # or something similar?

My data files will always be ordered in this same order, with "Data" at the bottom, if that helps.

Comment: I think you will have to write own code for this. But if `Data` is always at the end then you may need to read as normal string (or lines of file), search word `"Data":` and read all to the end of file, and later add `{` before `"Data"` to have correct JSON only with `"Data"`. And if you get all before `"Data":` and add `}` at the end then you will have correc JSON without `"Data"`

Answer (score 2):

What you have is pretty efficient, honestly. (You could swap in a different, faster JSON parser such as [`orjson`](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/) if you like.) Trying to mangle and parse the JSON data "by hand" to just extract `Data` is likely to be brittle and not worth it.

When you get to the point where you have 10M entries in the `"Data"` lists in the JSON, you'll likely have considered using something other than JSON for interchange anyway, since *encoding* such a JSON file will have taken a while as well – not to mention that `pandas` will need to spend a while inferring e.g. data formats from that dict where another format wouldn't need that.

Comment: That's a good point that writing the JSON file every few mins might end up taking a lot of time...  may have to rethink the way that data is captured.  Maybe the "Data" array can go into a separate text file, and only 'a'-mode append to it each time.

Comment: Just CSV would work for that file, then.